# Django Form refuses to render queryset in multiple select field

Tags: python, django, forms, field, django-queryset

I have the following django form:

```
class AccountForm(Form):

    evalTypes = django_fields.MultipleChoiceField(label="Default Evaluation Forms", widget=django_widgets.SelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # GET POSSIBLE LIST OF EVALUATIONS

        self.fields["evalTypes"].queryset = CustomForm.objects.filter(author__permissions__name__in=['manager'])

        for q in self.fields["evalTypes"].queryset:
            print q # THIS PRINTS ALL THE CORRECT VALUES
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded, the only thing that appears is the empty select box. This is strange because I have clear proof that queryset is being populated correctly. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) takes `choices` and not `queryset`

use [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) instead

```
evalTypes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Default Evaluation Forms", widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. The only thing is you need to pass a queryset parameter to MultipleChoiceField. So I did:

MultipleChoiceField(label="Default Evaluation Forms", widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=None)

Then added the queryset later.

Comment: yeah. i missed adding that part to the answer.